# assert() not evaluating code automatically

Tags: php, code-injection, assert

My PHP version is 7.2.9-1. There is a code injection on line `assert` in the following exercise:

```
extract($_POST);
function goAway() {
    error_log("Hacking attempt.");
    header('Location: /error/');
}

if (!isset($pi) || !is_numeric($pi)) {
    goAway();
}

if (!assert("(int)$pi == 3")) {
    echo "This is not pi.";
} else {
    echo "This might be pi.";
}
```

The operation assert() evaluates PHP code and it contains user input. However, I used `pi=phpinfo()` and the server does not `phpinfo()` but only outputs `This might be pi.`. Could someone explain this?

Answer (score 0):

From the PHP manual:

> Assertions should not be used for normal runtime operations like input parameter checks. As a rule of thumb your code should always be able to work correctly if assertion checking is not activated.

It might be possible that assertions are simply disabled in your PHP configuration. Check your `php.ini` file or `assert_options()`.

Furthermore based on the code sample you provided, this is **NOT** what `assert` is intended to be used for.